# Wagtail, change allowed extensions for WagtailImageField

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to add extra extensions    `wagtail.images.fields.WagtailImageField`

How it can be done? I've tried https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/settings.html#wagtailimages-extensions , but seems like this is not the correct option

P.S. based on comments. Seems like the problem is that wagtail version in my application is 4

Comment: WAGTAILIMAGES_EXTENSIONS definitely seems correct to me: see https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/1c5c802f10db2d972f53eecfdb02c905be3d0da4/wagtail/images/fields.py#L13-L32. What exactly did you try, and what went wrong?

Comment: @gasman - Oh, my current wagtail version is 4